# C/C++/Java question: will the expression used in for loop evaluate multiple times?

Tags: java, c++, c

for example,we have code like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < function(); ++i )
{
   // loop body;
}
```

will the function() be evaluated for each loop?

Comment: What language is C/C++/Java? Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

In most cases, the function will be called mutiple times.

However:

In C++, if it's a very simple function and make 'inline', then it's possible that there's no function call there indeed.

And in Java, if it's simple as well, JIT of VM may optimize it to reduce the unnecessary calls.

Comment: Even inline function will be called multiple times. Only a function returning a constant can be optimized out.

Comment: @Vladimir: not true: if the function returns a variable, and the optimiser sees that variable is not modified within the loop, then it's entirely legal to read it into a CPU register and continually check against that.  That's renders `for (i = start; i != function(); ++i) ...` exactly equivalent to the `end = function(); for (i = start; i != end; ++i) ...` case.

Comment: I may have forgotten C++ in 10 years with Java, but a quick test with G++ -O4 shown that function is called multiple times even when it can be totally optimized off.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It will be evaluated in each iteration of the loop. It must be because the there is a possibility that the function can return a different value each time it is called. Also, there may be a side-effect of calling the function (e.g. changing the value of a variable or writing a file). The compiler cannot assume otherwise. If that behavior is not desirable, you can use this for loop syntax to do only 1 calculation:

```
for (i = 0, len=function(); i < len; ++i )
{
   // loop body;
}
```

### Update:

Some have noted that there are certain edge cases where compilers can optimize away the multiple calls: e.g. const or inline functions in C++ that have no side effects, or a possibly when the JVM can infer that the function is repeatable and has no side-effects. But if you want a guarantee, and not rely on something that a compiler *might* do for you, I still recommend the for loop syntax mentioned above.

Comment: Not true, in C++, if the function has been marked "const"; in that case, the compiler can make the optimization.

Comment: @Michael Aaron Safyan: What if the function has a side effect?

Comment: @Asaph, good point. Even a function marked "const" can mutate global variables or print things. It's not something a compiler can or should normally do unless you tell it to do agressive optimizations.

Comment: @Asaph Even when `function()` has no side effect, the compiler is not 100% sure it can make the optimization: the loop body could affect the result of the `function()` call. E.g. `std::string s = "1234"; for(int i=0; i < s.length(); ++i) { s = "12"; }` Only by analysing both `function()`, the loop body, and everything called from both, the compiler could prove this. It's a rare case that the compiler is able to do this (therefore I doubt compilers even try), so if it matters, I suggest to rewrite it to the optimized version yourself.

Comment: @Sjoerd: if the function is inline then optimisers will "try": for example, in C++ it is idiomatic to code `for (I i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i) ...`, and so implementations of Standard containers typically (e.g. all GCCs) make sure `end()` is an inline reference to an existing value (not even needing a subtraction or addition) to ensure there's no performance penalty.

Comment: But end() is still called multiple times; just inlined. Penalty avoided is the penalty of allocating stack frame, nothing more. Body of end() HAS to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in all three languages.

To avoid this, you can put the result of `function()` into a variable:

```
int funcVal = function();
for (i = 0; i < funcVal; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

The compiler/JVM can't optimize this away for you (except in certain trivial cases) because `function()` might have a side-effect, for example printing to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Cameron's answer, you can write

```
for(int i = 0, funcVal = function(); i < funcVal; ++i) {
    // ...
}
```

As @RollingBoy suggests, the function() can be in-lined in C++ (by the compiler) and Java (by the JVM) and possibly optimized so it is not evaluated more than once.

Comment: Inlined doesn't mean "called once". Just actual call/ret is omitted; the body is still executed multiple times.

Comment: If all it does is a lookup of a field, like a size, this can be turning in a value which is not obtained from memory each time and do the same thing.